# Jmail Classic ASP upload file and send

Tags: html, email, asp-classic, jmail

I would like to know how to upload a file and send by mail using Classic ASP and Jmail, I would like to select the file using HTML type=file.

Comment: Can you add your code here? and let us know what issues you faced?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have 2 things to solve here the uploading of file, and the attachment of it to an outbound e-mail.

You will probably require a third party upload component - many Windows hosting companies have the 'Persits' suite of ASP components ready for use with working demos.
Is this your own server or a shared hosting etc? As there may be implications on shared hosting with what you can actually do - e.g. max file size, type of file etc.

The sample code should help you but note the 'somecomponent' bit obviously need to be inline with whatever you use.

Upload - Send an email with attachment
    <%
    'Sample file Form-Email.asp 
    ' Let's you send one an email with one or more attachments.

```
'Create upload form
Dim Form: Set Form = Server.CreateObject("SomeComponent.ASPForm")

'Do not upload data greater than 1MB. 
Form.SizeLimit = 100*1024

Const fscompleted  = 0

If Form.State = fscompleted Then 'completed
  ProcessForm
End If 


Sub ProcessForm
  Dim eFrom, eTo, Subject, Message

  'get source form fields - From, To, Subject and Message
  eFrom = Form("From")
  eTo = Form("To")
  Subject = Form("Subject")
  Message = Form("Message")

  Dim objNewMail, File, FileName, FS, TempFolder

  Set FS = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
  'Get temporary folder
  TempFolder = FS.GetSpecialFolder(2) & "\emailtemp"

  'Create a new email message
  Set objNewMail = CreateObject("CDONTS.NewMail")
  Const CdoMailFormatMime = 0
  objNewMail.MailFormat = CdoMailFormatMime
  'Save source files to temporary folder
  'Add these files to the new e-mail
  For Each File In Form.Files
    'If source file is specified.
    If Len(File.FileName) > 0 Then
      FileName = TempFolder & "\" & File.FileName 

      File.SaveAs FileName

      objNewMail.AttachFile FileName
    End If
  Next

  'Send the new email
  objNewMail.Send eFrom, eTo, Subject, Message

  'delete temporary files
  For Each File In Form.Files
    If Len(File.FileName) > 0 Then
      FileName = TempFolder & "\" & File.FileName 
      FS.DeleteFile FileName
    End If
  Next
End Sub

%>  
<br>Sample For <A Href=http://www.motobit.com>HugeASP upload</A>
<br> Let's you send one an email with one or more attachments.
<br> File size limit Is <%=Form.SizeLimit%> B (<%=Form.SizeLimit \ 1024 %>kB).
<Table Border=0>
<form method="POST" ENCTYPE="multipart/form-data">
  <tr><td> From : </td><td><input Name=From Size=50></td></tr>

  <tr><td> To : </td><td><input Name=To Size=50></td></tr>

  <tr><td> Subject : </td><td><input Name=Subject Size=80></td></tr>

  <tr><td ColSpan=2> Message:
    <br><TextArea Name=Message Cols=76 Rows=10></TextArea>
  </td></tr>

  <tr><td ColSpan=2>E-Mail Attachments:
    <Div ID=files>
       Attachment 1 : <input type="file" name="File1">
    </Div>
    <Input Type=Button Value="Add a file" OnClick=return(Expand()) 
     Style="border=0;background=yellow;cursor:hand">
  </td></tr>

  <tr><td ColSpan=2 Align=Right>
    <input Name=SubmitButton Value="Send email >>" Type=Submit></td></tr>
  </Form>
</Table>

<Script>
//Script To add a attachment file field 
var nfiles = 1;
Function Expand(){
  nfiles++
  var adh = '<BR> Attachment '+nfiles+' : <input type="file" 
 name="File'+nfiles+'">';
  files.insertAdjacentHTML('BeforeEnd',adh);
  return false;
}
</Script>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I will try to implement those code and test them in our own servers (we host the web server and the mail server).

Comment: The OP has said that he's using Jmail, but anyway I wouldn't recommend using CDONTS any more, it wasn't included on Windows Server 2003 or any version since.  CDOSYS is the default mail component on current versions